# How to configure 448 subplots?

Tags: python, image, for-loop, matplotlib, subplot

I have a piece of code which is inputting a total of 448 thumbnail images and i need to display them in with 64 rows and 7 columns. The code I have does this but the images are so small they are completely useless. I've attached the image and the code i currently have. Any suggestions as to how i can get them to display large enough to see?
[image: subplots]

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import csv
import os
import matplotlib.image as img
plt.close('all')
ID=np.array([])
cata=csv.reader(open('final_final_list.csv',"rU"))
for x in cata:
    ID=np.append(ID,x[0])

plots_acc=np.array([])
for i in range(0,len(ID)):

    plots_acc=np.append(plots_acc,'filt_image/'+ID[i]+'/'+'ugr.png')                       #appending the file location for each of the object filter images
    plots_acc=np.append(plots_acc,'filt_image/'+ID[i]+'/'+'i1.png')
    plots_acc=np.append(plots_acc,'filt_image/'+ID[i]+'/'+'z.png')
    plots_acc=np.append(plots_acc,'filt_image/'+ID[i]+'/'+'Y.png')
    plots_acc=np.append(plots_acc,'filt_image/'+ID[i]+'/'+'J.png')
    plots_acc=np.append(plots_acc,'filt_image/'+ID[i]+'/'+'H.png')
    plots_acc=np.append(plots_acc,'filt_image/'+ID[i]+'/'+'Ks.png')
    text=(['ugr','i1','z','Y','J','H','Ks'])


print plots_acc
plt.figure()    
for x in range(0,len(plots_acc)):                                                                            #creating subplot of filter images
    plt.subplot(64,7,x)
    plots=img.imread(plots_acc[x])
    plt.imshow(plots)
    plt.axis('off')

    #plt.suptitle(ID[i])
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0, wspace=0.0, bottom=0.63)
    #plt.savefig('accepted object images/'+str(ID[i])+'.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be better and faster to create a single plot of an image that is created from the stitching of the 64x7 individual images.

Comment: could you possibly point me in the direction of somewhere that shows how to do that?

Comment: I'm not an expert in python image processing, but the PIL library should do that task quite easily. Take a look at https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/tutorial.html